# How can I set the dots on an unordered list and change them to images on hover

Tags: html, css

I have tried to remove the bullet points in an unordered list using this CSS:

```
list-style-type:none
```

But how do I change them to images on hover?

like this

**simple li**:- https://prnt.sc/u8bml0

**remove li douts**:- https://prnt.sc/u8bml0

**replace img like this**:- https://prnt.sc/u8bnzd

**hover to show like this:**- https://prnt.sc/u8bnzd

My code is like this:

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

This is the link to the image I would like the list's bullet points to be: https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/coffee_3054889?term=coffee&page=1&position=2

This is what I'd like them to be on hover: https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/coffee_2935500?term=coffee&page=1&position=9

I am just learning HTML and CSS.

Comment: You can search [ html - image changing on li / a hover ] but if it doesn't works, you can then tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
ul {
  list-style-image: url('sqpurple.gif');
}
ul li:hover {
    list-style-image: url('roung.gif');
}
</style>
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll replace the douts with image

```
ul {
  list-style-image: url('sqpurple.gif');
}
```

And hover to change li image

```
ul li:hover {
    list-style-image: url('roung.gif');
}
```